# Apply svg inline styling for rotating an icon

Tags: css, reactjs, svg

I am importing an icon from the library and would like to rotate it by 90 deg in my code to make it look like my requirement. I am trying to apply transform attribute but its not working. It's working fine when I try that attribute in developer tools.

```
<IconButton
        flat
        primary
        icon={
          isAllExpanded ? (
            <ChevronRightDoubleIcon width={16} color={ICON_COLOR} transform='rotate(90deg)'/>
          ) : (
            <ChevronLeftDoubleIcon color={ICON_COLOR} />
          )
        }
      />
```

I also tried to wrap it in a separate div element and apply css styling but that changes all the icons in the page even though I wrap the div element around this Iconbutton.

```
<DoubleArrow>
      <IconButton
        flat
        primary
        icon={
          isAllExpanded ? (
            <ChevronRightDoubleIcon width={16} color={ICON_COLOR} />
          ) : (
            <ChevronLeftDoubleIcon color={ICON_COLOR} />
          )
        }
      />
      </DoubleArrow>

export const DoubleArrow = styled.div`
  #ChevronRightDoubleIcon {
  svg {
      transform: rotate(90deg);
    }
`;
```

Is there a way to apply svg transform styling when I use the icon tag that I need ?

Comment: Css can be set via `style` attribute. `style={{transform: 'rotate(90deg)'}}` will probably work. the `transform` prop you're setting is most likely the [svg attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform), the syntax is different from css, something like `transform='rotate(90 0 0)'` would probably work.
[Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-icons-forked-25xw5m?file=/src/components/IconButtons.js:240-247)

Comment: I had tried rotate(90,0,0) but that didnt work for me. But putting it within style attribute worked! 
style={{transform: 'rotate(90deg)'}} is what worked!

Comment: The SVG transform syntax is a bit finicky, notice that there's no comma's between the values. `transform='rotate(90 0 0)'` should work. In any case I would probably stick with the  css solution regardless. Cheers.

Comment: I don't grok enough of your code to be sure, but why not bake the rotation into the SVG? Throw it into Photopea, rotate, and export out a new file. Done! No further need to mess w transforms. I do this when I need to flip or move something bc Safari's transform origin bugs are a huge pain, leading to wildly unexpected results.

You could also try CSS rotate inside the SVG itself using inline styles, instead of from your code/IDE. Also maybe try to apply the transform to the <path> or wrap the path w/ a <g> and transform the <g>, instead of transforming the root <svg>.